# Drop_existing throws an error if index does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, indexing

I'm creating/changing a ton of indexes on a large db. Doing this works if the index already exists.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED
INDEX [table1_1] ON [dbo].[table1] ([col1], [col2], [col3])
WITH DROP_EXISTING ON [PRIMARY]
```

But if it does not exist the errors.

So I have changed my script to:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysindexes WHERE name = 'table1_1') DROP INDEX [table1].[table1_1]
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED
INDEX [table1_1] ON [dbo].[table1] ([col1], [col2], [col3])
ON [PRIMARY]
```

So the question is am I using WITH DROP_EXISTING wrong?

Comment: For performance reasons, you might want to IF/ELSE it like so: IF index exists THEN create with drop_existing ELSE create (without drop_existing)

Comment: @PhilipKelley true, but this creates dublicate code. Any additionaly suggestions to handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is a limitation of `DROP_EXISTING`, it does fail if the index did not already exist! (At least on MS SQL 2000 and 2005)

Reference: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1362

Comment: I can confirm the same limitation for SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I can confirm this buggy behaviour on SQL 2016 SP1.

Comment: this is a ridiculous limitation